# Double colon in function declaration

Tags: php, function, symfony

While reading [a post on Medium](https://medium.com/@mlbors/getting-started-with-symfony-4-9169583a1710), I stumbled upon a function signature I couldn't understand.

```
public function index(): Response
{
    $posts = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Post::class)
                ->findAll();
    return $this->render('posts/list.html.twig', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

What is the purpose of `: Response` in this case ? Is it specific to Symfony ?

Comment: It's PHP 7 syntax, the method return type, and no, it's not specific to Symfony.

Comment: p.s. for future reference, that "double dot" is a colon :)

Comment: ... and it is not an operator.

Comment: Read about [return type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration).

Comment: Then there is the "double dot with a twist" `;`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "double dot" misleading translation come from the french "deux points". I let it in the subject to help people doing similar mistake find this question

Comment: My mistake, I should have called that a colon .. But your guess was right, since I'm Belgian and I speak french :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PHP 7** adds support for [return type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration). Similarly to argument type declarations, return type declarations specify the type of the value that will be returned from a function. The same types are available for return type declarations as are available for argument type declarations.

Strict typing also has an effect on return type declarations. In the default weak mode, returned values will be coerced to the correct type if they are not already of that type. In strong mode, the returned value must be of the correct type, otherwise a TypeError will be thrown.

**PHP 7.1** adds a nullable return type, declared like `: ?string`

Some example:

```
function getNothing(): void {
    return; // valid
}

function getNothing(): void {
    // do nothing
    // valid
}

function getAge(): ?int  {
    return null; // valid
}

function getAge(): ?int  {
    return 18; // valid
}

function getAge(): int  {
    return 18; // valid
}

function getAge(): ?int  {
    return null; // valid
}

function getAge(): int  {
    return null; // error
}
```